# DataFrame empty after scraping using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape dynamic webpage livescore.com, using Python and Requests-HTML, football match results, but I got an empty DataFrame errors.

This is my code:

```
import schedule
import time
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 

def task():

    matchlink = 'https://www.flashscore.com'

    from requests_html import HTMLSession
    session = HTMLSession()
    
    r = session.get(matchlink)
    r.html.render(timeout=20)

    

    times = r.html.find(".event__time")
    home_teams = r.html.find(".event__participant.event__participant--home") 
    scoresh = r.html.find(".event__score event__score--home")
    away_teams = r.html.find(".event__participant.event__participant--away")
    scoresa = r.html.find(".event__score event__score--away")

    dict_res = defaultdict(list)

    for ind in range(len(times)):
        dict_res['times'].append(times[ind].text)
        dict_res['home_teams'].append(home_teams[ind].text)
        dict_res['scoresh'].append(scoresh[ind].text)
        dict_res['away_teams'].append(away_teams[ind].text)
        dict_res['scoresa'].append(scoresa[ind].text)

    print(pd.DataFrame(dict_res))
    

    

    session.close()

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(task)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I got this error:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

I'm getting crazy with this code, I hope someone could help me

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace. Also, a little tip, put all your imports at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Itération122442 Thanks for your answer, I posted my full code there and, when I run it, I get this: PS C:\xampp\htdocs\livescores>  c:; cd 'c:\xampp\htdocs\livescores'; & 'C:\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\ASUS\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '56929' '--' 'c:\xampp\htdocs\livescores\wehen.py' 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []